# Padding right for img only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a script which allows to display favicon based on the url over here: [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/udukut/4/edit)

I have set a padding right for img in the css. Th problem is that the second url(nu.nl) is also getting the css `padding right` while there is no favicon img. How can I set the css or change the script so that my img styling would only effect the img and not the other urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you can set width to imgs like this. And you can use margin for the image.

`img {margin-right: 10px;width:16px;height:16px;}`

if there is no image, there will be a blank square.

Edit:

if there is no image, the image will not be displayed with jsvascirpt.
i am added the following lines :

```
extImg.onerror = function(){
    faviconIMG.css({'display':'none'});
    console.log("error --------------");
};
```

http://jsbin.com/udukut/9/edit

Comment: Thats the problem..I dont want a blank squire

Comment: ok. if there is not any the favicon, are there nothing on the image?

Comment: the problem is that the Text is 'MOVING' to the right even if there is NO img

Comment: i change the jsbin file. with some js codes. i will explain it.

Comment: now it is not moving when the image if the image is not found.

Comment: Thanks for sticking around and solving the problem:)

Answer (score 3):

You have to make some class or ID to target certain images only,
 because right now padding right is applied on all image tag.

```
.Myimages(images which have padding-right)
{
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

Now use this class everywhere you want, for padding-right:10px

I am not sure but this could work please check

```
 var faviconIMG    = jQuery('<img src="' + '" alt="" class="Myimages"/>')[config.insert](link);
```

Right now its applying in all image tags because you have applied padding right on `img` which will effect all the tags having img.

Comment: How do I do that?? The problem is that there is no img but the script does ad kinda of a ghost img, which is not really there but does take up space..

Comment: That doesnt work..(please give me an example if you think it does) This is basic knowledge, youre missing the problem..

Comment: you have to break the function in two parts i guess because the css class will apply on every new image so you have to do something else in which the particular function will avoid this class, I dont know Jscript :( cant help but i can suggest you at my end this can be a solution

Answer (score 1):

You could give the image a class

```
<style>
   .foo {padding-right: 10px}
</style>

<img src="/link/to/img.jpg" class="foo" />
```

Comment: Please give me an example in the JsBin. This doesnt work..(I think you should take a look at the script or read question again)

Comment: Try to give the link a class and set the link's padding to 0

Answer (score 0):

Insert `IMG` element into link on `load` event for the image instead of inserting `IMG` element into all links regardless of whether favicon is actually loaded.

Comment: I understand. how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use jQuery to handle the broken images after it's already created them? Extra overheads, but works okay.

`$("img").error(function(){
  $(this).attr('style','padding: 0px;');
});`